# How long does it take for a beta version of my app to be released onto production for android (play store)?

Tags: android

If I released a closed beta version of my app to production on the play store how long will it take to show on the play store for all my users?

Also, will the app have to be reviewed again since it has already been reviewed when I released it to beta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing with the Play Store support team and with other app developers I received these answers.

The review process is mainly automated and they have reviewers for certain scenarios.

The review process for a beta release and a production release is exactly the same.

If you promote a beta release to become a production release it needs to be reviewed again.

The review process time varies depending on multiple factors. An example of this is another developer's app that was reviewed on average within 4 days and he works for a banking app. Whilst other apps were reviewed (including mine) within 24 hours on average.

Answer (score 1):

Darren,

Take a look [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282?hl=en-GB), it gives most of the info you're looking for.  The average time is between 5 - 7 days however, due to CV-19 there is "Longer than usual" review times for your app.

Your app will be reviewed when it goes into production.  Hope that helps. if it does...click the tick next to this answer.

Comment: This " The average time is between 5 - 7 days however " is only for certain accounts, normally must be in some hours

Comment: In my case it was 3 days, I recommend you do it on Thursday or Friday and on Monday you will see it on play store

Comment: for new app, for an update it takes between 30 mins to 1 hour

Comment: I was wondering if the times differ between just releasing straight to production or if it's different if you release to beta and then to production and if so what are the average wait times?

Comment: There is no real average, it depends on server loads and a number of other variables. In my experience however, it's usually 24 hours max

Answer (score 0):

There is no defined time for your app deployment; for an update usually you will have to wait for a few hours for the app to be delivered to all Google servers.

For a new app you will have to wait from hours to days.

Google uses an algorithm to analyse your app for violations, but from my experience, if you suffered a previous violation, it was rejected or suspended previously, you app will need more time  in order to be released.

> Note: For certain developer accounts, we’ll take more time to
> thoroughly review your app(s) to help better protect users. This may
> result in review times of up to 7 days or longer in exceptional cases.
> You’ll receive a notification on your app's Dashboard about how long
> this should take.